# ngMockE2E - error after adding to dependencies

Tags: angularjs

after I add ngMockE2E into dependencies the page goes into error and it can not load view html

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET views/main.html
No more request expected
```

my dependencies:

```
angular
  .module('mockApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',
    'ngMockE2E'
  ])
```

without the last line everything is ok

I have added files into index.html and loaded libraries with bower. I can print the $httpBackend in run method and it prints the source code

```
.run(function($httpBackend, $log) {
  $log.debug('got there backend: ' + $httpBackend);
});
```

Comment: Do you discover what is wrong? I have the same problem here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a pass-through for your templates after all your simulated requests (see, [official API reference for $httpBackend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMockE2E/service/$httpBackend)).

Given a module named *my-app* and a folder *views* containing all of your templates, this code should solve your problem.

```
angular.module('my-app').run(function($httpBackend) {

    [ . . . $httpBackend requests . . . ]    

    $httpBackend.whenGET(/^views\/.*/).passThrough();  

    [ . . . remaining logic, but no $httpBackend requests . . . ]

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I discover what is wrong.

After create a mock, you need to bypass the model pages (in my project, there are .html files), using:

```
app.run(function($httpBackend) {
    ...
    $httpBackend.whenGET(/\.html$/).passThrough();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While trying to load something like below.

```
<div data-ng-include="'/app/UI/home.html'"></div>
```

This would work fine if

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

but not when

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMockE2E']);
```

No console errors, no rendered view. To avoid this use

```
myApp.run(function ($httpBackend) {

    $httpBackend.whenGET(new RegExp('app\/.*')).passThrough();

});
```

This line allows you request to pass through for every resource containing app/as folder root.